# How to clone an existing Firebase project data to another new project?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-remote-config

I want to clone an existing Firebase project, lets name it `ProjectA` that previously exists on Firebase console with some [Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/) data to another new project(without any [Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/) data), lets name it `ProjectB`.

The idea behind my question is that currently I have developed an Android app that is using the `google-service.json`(Firebase configuration file) file from the `ProjectA`, so I want to create/clone a new Firebase project `ProjectB`(**NOTE:** I don't want a new Firebase app on the same project) that starts with exactly the same [Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/) data from `ProjectA` and then add the `google-service.json` from the new `ProjectB` to my new Android app.

I have read the [firebase-cli](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/) documentation but looks like it's out of its scope.

Has someone accomplished something similar like this or has an idea how can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just created [this ruby gem](https://github.com/epool/firebase-cloning-tool) to automate the manual process that I needed to do from a web browser for cloning my remote config data from `ProjectA` to a my new `ProjectB`.

**NOTE:** The gem is really an alpha version and just consider remote config without any rules. If some of you want to fork it and improved please feel free to do that.

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no way (neither through the Console or through an API) to create a project that is a clone of another project. At the moment you will have to re-create the config data in the new project manually.

Comment: This is possible now?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase documents a flow to move data between projects here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/move-data

Though the method they outline requires a billed account.

Comment: this is only for firestore. OP has needs beyond that, such as Remote Config

Answer (score 1):

A few months ago Firebase started supporting Terraform which is a IaaC (Infrastructure as a Code) tool. You can configure your Firebase projects in your terraform files and create your environment without using the Firebase Console.

Reference:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32SKh-jGXI4&t=53s